# Missing geometry in Sentinel 2 footprints

Tags: sentinel-2, amazon-web-services

I've noticed some scenes on bucket that contain empty (no geometry) detector footprint masks. Examples:
http://sentinel-s2-l1c.s3.amazonaws.com/tiles/11/S/MT/2016/8/17/0/qi/MSK_DETFOO_B03.gml
http://sentinel-s2-l1c.s3.amazonaws.com/tiles/36/L/XR/2017/11/10/0/qi/MSK_DETFOO_B04.gml

I didn't find it mentioned in Sentinel 2 quality report. I'm sorry to bother, I know it's not the right place to report an issue. Where should I report issues related to Sentinel 2 on AWS?

UPDATE:
I have checked the masks at Copernicus SciHub and they are empty as well. So I wrote to EO Support.

Comment: These gml files are not changed during ingestion (apart of the renaming) so there is very high chance that this is an error of ESA, not ingestion. The fact that it is not in the quality report means only that nobody reported that yet...  I suggest you first go to Copernicus OpenHub and check, whether the data are empty there as well. If yes, report this to EO Support. If not, it might be that they have reprocessed this file but not told ingested it properly so AWS replication did not pick it up. My bet is that GMLs are empty on OpenHub as well.

Comment: @GregaM., you were right. I've checked the GMLs on OpenHub and they are empty as well. So I'm writing to EO Support

Comment: @GregaM. Please consider adding your comment as an answer so this question can be closed as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the GMLs at Copernicus SciHub and they were empty as well, so I wrote to Copernicus EO Support. They answered that this is a known issue that arises as a consequence of missing ancillary packets in the product. And unfortunately, there is currently no way to regenerate the DETFOO from the existing tile footprint.

Answer (score 3):

These GML files are not changed during ingestion (apart of the renaming) so there is very high chance that this is an error of ESA, not ingestion. The fact that it is not in the quality report means only that nobody reported that yet...